# How to remove all the non numeric characters from column in mysql in bulk data

Tags: mysql

I want to remove all the non numeric characters from the column. I have bulk data in my database.

Currently I am using method as describe in below link:

http://venerableagents.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/mysql-numeric-functions/

The problem is that its taking too much time for preocessing.

For 1 million of row current logic takes 1 hour to process the data.

please help me..

Thank You,
Ronak

Comment: Any luck with my solution? I reckon it could be a very good contender!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing something like:

```
update myTable set foo = NumericOnly(foo);
```

I don't know how much better you can do than that.

One thing that might help a bit, though. In that `NumericOnly` function, they're doing extra work.  I'd remove the `SET idx = LENGTH(val)+1;` line, since all that will do is start checking the end of the string (the parts we've *already* checked) again.  A string with 5 leading non-numerics would be checked, in full, 5 times.

Removing the line would leave:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS NumericOnly;

CREATE FUNCTION NumericOnly (val VARCHAR(255)) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
 DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;
 IF ISNULL(val) THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;

 IF LENGTH(val) = 0 THEN RETURN ""; END IF;

 SET idx = LENGTH(val);
  WHILE idx > 0 DO
    IF IsNumeric(SUBSTRING(val,idx,1)) = 0 THEN
     SET val = REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,idx,1),"");
    END IF;
    SET idx = idx - 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN val;
 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another spin on things...

**DEMO:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c96e/21

First, create yourself a **numbers table**

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
   number int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO numbers (number)
SELECT n0 + n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5
FROM   (SELECT 0 AS n0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) AS z0
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n1 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 12) AS z1
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n2 UNION SELECT 16 UNION SELECT 32 UNION SELECT 48) AS z2
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n3 UNION SELECT 64 UNION SELECT 128 UNION SELECT 192) AS z3
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n4 UNION SELECT 256 UNION SELECT 512 UNION SELECT 768) AS z4
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n5 UNION SELECT 1024 UNION SELECT 2048 UNION SELECT 3072) AS z5
ORDER
    BY 1;
```

Here's some sample data to play with

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
   foo varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO your_table (foo)
  VALUES ('124nhasfonasf13')
       , ('NONE')
       , ('r937')
       , ('o9o9')
       , ('n444n4n455n')
       , ('blah');
```

Then here's a query to give you just the numbers. Should be more efficient as it is SET based instead of iterative like your function example...

```
SELECT foo
     , Group_Concat(c ORDER BY position SEPARATOR '')
FROM   (
        SELECT vals.foo
             , numbers.number As position
             , SubString(vals.foo, numbers.number, 1) As c
        FROM   (
                SELECT foo
                     , Length(foo) As lngth
                FROM   your_table
                WHERE  foo REGEXP '[0-9]'
               ) As vals
         INNER
          JOIN numbers
            ON numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND vals.lngth
       ) As x
WHERE  c REGEXP '[0-9]'
GROUP
    BY foo
```