# MySQL query to clean up phone numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with three columns, `PhoneHome`, `PhoneCell`, and `PhoneWork` (mind you, I did not set up this table), and I'm trying to clean up these columns so that all the phone numbers are displayed like so: 999-999-9999. Some of the rows also have text like (999-999-9999 John's cell, or (999) 999-9999 Sarah), I just want to filter everything out, and only keep the phone numbers and like this-> 999-999-9999. I know that I'm going to have to use a RegExp to handle this, I'm just not sure how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should tale a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660482/how-to-remove-all-the-non-numeric-characters-from-column-in-mysql-in-bulk-data

Answer (score 0):

You can identify phone numbers that match (or don't match) the patter using a regular expression.  For instance, to get home phones that match your pattern:

```
select PhoneHome
from table t
where PhoneHome regexp '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$'
```

Use `not regexp' for those that don't match.