# How to remove non-numeric characters from MySQL cells

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with ~200,000 rows. There are three different phone number columns and the data in them is not all formatted the same. I'd like to remove any value that is not a number and update every cell.

For instance, `(412)641-5892` becomes `4126415892`.

I found this STRIP_NON_DIGIT() function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287105/mysql-strip-non-numeric-characters-to-compare). I can use that in my SQL queries and it works properly, but it takes a minute to return a result. I'd like to run a mass UPDATE across the entire table, but not sure what the syntax is for that.

Something like this is what I'm going for.

```
UPDATE leads 
SET phone    = STRIP_NON_DIGIT(phone), 
mobile_phone = STRIP_NON_DIGIT(mobile_phone), 
home_phone   = STRIP_NON_DIGIT(home_phone)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660482/how-to-remove-all-the-non-numeric-characters-from-column-in-mysql-in-bulk-data see if that is what you need

Comment: And what's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Make sure you fix the future before you fix the past.  That way you only have to fix the past once.

Comment: @Shadow I just thought I was writing pseudo code! Just ran it and it seems to have worked perfectly.

Comment: In this case pls delete the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was the pseudo code that I wrote!